# Envoy and statsd Error: node 'id' and 'cluster' id are required

Tags: statsd, envoyproxy

I am trying to configure stats sink to collect stats into `statsd`.

I have configured the envoy.yaml as follows:

```
admin:
  access_log_path: /logs/envoy_access.log
  address:
    socket_address:
      protocol: TCP
      address: 0.0.0.0
      port_value: 8001

stats_sinks:
  name: envoy.statsd
  config:
    tcp_cluster_name: statsd-exporter

static_resources:
  ...


  clusters:

    - name: app
      connect_timeout: 0.25s
      type: strict_dns
      lb_policy: round_robin
      hosts:
        - socket_address:
            address: {{appName}}
            port_value: {{appPort}}

    - name: statsd-exporter
      connect_timeout: 0.25s
      type: strict_dns
      lb_policy: round_robin
      hosts:
        - socket_address:
            address: statsd_exporter
            port_value: 9125
```

`statsd` is built as container within the same docker network.

When I run the docker containers with Envoy and statsd, Envoy shows the following error:

```
proxy_1            | [2019-05-06 04:50:38.006][27][info][main] [source/server/server.cc:516] exiting
proxy_1            | tcp statsd: node 'id' and 'cluster' are required. Set it either in 'node'
config or via --service-node and --service-cluster options.
template-starter-windows_proxy_1 exited with code 1
```

How do I resolve this error?

**Update**

I was able to resolve the error by setting the --service-cluster and --service-node parameters for envoy command:
`envoy -c /etc/envoy/envoy.yaml --service-cluster 'front-envoy' --service-node 'front-envoy'`

I am not sure why using statsd sink would require these parameters to be set. and The documentation for envoy does not mention this information,

Comment: The docs may not have mentioned this at the time you ran into this problem, but the docs do mention these as requirements now: [service cluster](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.8.0/operations/cli#cmdoption-service-cluster) and [service node](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.8.0/operations/cli#cmdoption-service-node). The docs on the [stats](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v2/config/metrics/v2/stats.proto#envoy-api-msg-config-metrics-v2-statsdsink) section don't mention that those are required though, so it seems like this is a matter of clarity in the docs.

Comment: The docs may not have mentioned this at the time you ran into this problem, but the docs do mention these as requirements now: [service cluster](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.8.0/operations/cli#cmdoption-service-cluster) and [service node](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.8.0/operations/cli#cmdoption-service-node). The docs on the [stats](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v2/config/metrics/v2/stats.proto#envoy-api-msg-config-metrics-v2-statsdsink) section don't mention that those are required though, so it seems like this is a matter of clarity in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the docs suggest passing argument flags to bypass the error. I agree this is unsatisfying. I'm not sure why the docs under "examples" don't provide working yaml out of the box.

To use `envoy.yml` to the same configuration as these CLI args, I've added the following top level entry:

```yaml
node:
  id: foo_id
  cluster: foo_cluster
```

so your full `envoy.yml` will look some thing like:

```yaml
node:
  id: foo_id
  cluster: foo_cluster

admin:
  ...
  ...

stats_sinks:
  ...
  ...

static_resources:
  ...
  ...
```